# Pairing values of a child and nested child element from parsed XML files

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

I'm using Python and `elementTree` to attempt to parse some `XML` files as these have been indicated to be some of the better tools to use from what I've read.

The XML doc I'm trying to sort through is of this form:

```
<data>
 <property name="AText">
  <property value="BText">
   <property name="Id" value="DEVICE"/> #Pairing this value...
   <property name="CText" value="text">
     <property name="Value" value="This is a device."/> #...with this value is 
                                                         #proving problematic
   </property>
  </property>
  <property value="BText">
   <property name="Id" value="BRICK"/>
   <property name="CText" value="text">
     <property name="Value" value="This is a brick."/>
   </property>
   </property>
  </property>
</data>
```

What I've been able to do is the easy part, I've been able to drill down to the child elements I'm interested in and pull their text info. However, once I try to organize that info, I hit a snag, because I can't figure out how to pair the values of the children indicated above.

This is important because they don't make sense if arbitrarily paired. The text of the `Id` element's value is literally the ID of the `Value` element's value.

For now, my code has been:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

tree = ET.parse('sample2.exml')
root = tree.getroot()

shrt = 0
txt = 0
save = {"ID:" : shrt, "Desc.:" : txt}

for y in root.findall("./Property//*[@name='Id']"):
    shrt = y.get('value')
    save["ID:"] = shrt

for x in root.findall(".//*[@name='CText']/Property"):
    txt = x.get('value')
    save["Desc.:"] = txt

print(save)
```

This breaks down as soon as you get more pairs. I've tried lists, but this was the quickest (and cleanest) bit of code I still had available that I hadn't scrapped in my search for solutions.

My primary aim is simply to parse the XML for these elements and then organize them in the appropriate pairs. A later aim is to possibly write them to a table, retaining these pairings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key to pairing the attributes is to process them at the same time.  This bit of code loops looking for the property nodes, and then uses that portion of the sub-tree to continue finding the elements you need.

**Code:**

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

tree = ET.parse(xml_data)
root = tree.getroot()

results = []
for prop in root.findall(".//property/[@value='BText']"):
    results.append((
        prop.find(".//property/[@name='Id']").get('value'),
        prop.find(".//property/[@name='Value']").get('value'),
    ))

print(results)
```

**Test Data:**

```
from io import StringIO

xml_data = StringIO(u"""
    <data>
      <property name="AText">
        <property value="BText">
          <property name="Id" value="DEVICE"/> 
          <property name="CText" value="text"/>
          <property name="Value" value="This is a device."/>
        </property>
        <property value="BText">
          <property name="Id" value="BRICK"/>
          <property name="CText" value="text"/>
          <property name="Value" value="This is a brick."/>
        </property>
      </property>
    </data>
""")
```

**Results:**

```
[('DEVICE', 'This is a device.'), ('BRICK', 'This is a brick.')]
```

**Python is Fun:**

As a follow up, if you are not familiar with `namedtuple`s they are very slick.  They are tuples, that can also be access using named attributes. Here is the loop from above using namedtuples.

Bonus Code:

```
from collections import namedtuple
ItemDesc = namedtuple('ItemDesc', 'shrt txt')

results = []
for prop in root.findall(".//property/[@value='BText']"):
    results.append(ItemDesc(
        shrt=prop.find(".//property/[@name='Id']").get('value'),
        txt=prop.find(".//property/[@name='Value']").get('value'),
    ))

for item in results:
    print("shrt={}, txt={}".format(item.shrt, item.txt))
```

Bonus Results:

```
shrt=DEVICE, txt=This is a device.
shrt=BRICK, txt=This is a brick.
```

Comment: This is extremely close to what I was looking for. I made a minor error in the formatting of the XML above though. The CText lines are their own closed elements (i.e. `<property> </property>`), and as indicated, the Values are their children.

Sorry for the oversight!

Comment: Clarification: this worked, the issue was that I didn't adjust each line of the sample code properly to match my actual file's characteristics.